# How do i use props.theme.breakpoints with the makeStyles hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

So I am trying to use the material breakpoints https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/ given here along with the makeStyles hook. I am not able to use props.breakpoints.down('600') when trying to make responsive styling. How do I use breakpoints inside of the makeStyles hook ?

```
  bottom: '64px',
  height: '54px',
  backgroundImage: 'none',
  color: 'red'
}
```

I've tried this but it just doesnt work.

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  Container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: '5',
    bottom: '0',
    paddingTop: ' 1%',
    left: ' 0',
    zIndex: '10',
    width: '100vw',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(45, 49, 55, 0.81))',
    display: 'block',
    // height: "74px"
    height: props => props.captionHeight,
    [props => props.breakpoints.down('600')]: {
      bottom: '64px',
      height: '54px',
      backgroundImage: 'none',
      color: 'red'
    }
  }});

I expect to be able to have apply the styles when the screenwidth is lesser than 600px using the material-ui breakpoints api.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the 'breakpoints' property of theme to specify a breakpoint.
In this example, you get the background color property to be blue when the width of the window exceeds 600px.

Here is the working example in code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-benz-697f2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    s1: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('600')]: {
            backgroundColor: 'blue'
        }
    },
    s2: {
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
}));
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant if you are using material-ui version 5+

Comment: @KunalTyagi but the answer was given before the release of v5

Comment: This works for me in MUI5 also, @KunalTyagi can you point out what is not working?

Comment: It will work, but makeStyles is deprecated now and is expected to be removed in v6. So, it is no longer relevant

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {})
```

works!